In YAML, what does the period at the start of a line mean?
I'm working on a YAML config file for ESPHome and need to use some anchors to avoid a lot of repetition.  I've been having a really tough time finding information on YAML anchors and examples of more than just the simplest uses. In this case, I have, with someone's suggestion:
.number: &AnchorDelay
optimistic: true
min_value: 0
max_value: 600
step: 1
initial_value: 0
web_server: &AnchorDelayWebServer
  sorting_group_id: sorting_group_switchmain
  sorting_weight: 30

number:
  - platform: template
    <<: *AnchorDelay
    id: "SwitchMainDelay"
    name: "Main Switch Delay"

  - platform: template
    <<: *AnchorDelay
    id: "Switch01Delay"
    name: "Switch 01 Delay"
    web_server:
      << : *AnchorDelayWebServer
      sorting_group_id: sorting_group_switch1

In order to create the original component I wanted within the number: section, this format has been the only thing I could find. It seems to work, but I can't find clear documentation on what the .number with the dot/period at the start of the line does. I've searched and have not found any clear answer of just what that's about or what it does.

YAML format doesn't have special treatement of dots, even when they are placed at the beginning of scalars. Some parsers, however, may have specific in interpreting such scalars.

@Tsyvarev So this is not a YAML thing, but would be an ESPHome thing, since it's ESPHome that uses the YAML file?

Yes, ESPHome could have specific about using dots at the beginning of YAML keys. So you may edit the question to ask specifically about ESPHome. BTW, there is esphome tag on Stack Overflow. While the tag doesn't have a description, it seems to be about the same ESPHome as in your question.

@Tsyvarev Thank you. If you want to write that up as an answer, I'll go on and select it - might as well have a clear answer, even if it is, "There's no answer!"
